# Position "Magnet" when building a layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

This is my first question here simply because up until now I always found answers to my questions thanks to other's people questions...

The problem is that I don't know how to define my situation exactly,
I'll try though... So I'm new to developing android application and I'm using Eclipse.

To design the app as you know I'm using the XML layout editor. My problem is when I'm trying to design and add items.
I can't manage to put items (buttons etc.) where i want them to be, it sorts the components as if there is a magnet...

They have to be right next to each other or above each other and this is very annoying.

Same thing happens with the sizes of the items, I can't control the size of the items totally,
its either small or huge...

Whats causing this?

I think it has something to do with the orientation, when its set to vertical all items are placed one under the other, and on horizontal it is one right next to the other...

Thank you very much, and if i did something wrong asking my question please let me know ;)

Comment: well it all depends on your base layout, if you're using a `FrameLayout` or a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`? Also if you can post a specific example of your xml what it looks like and what you want it to look like we can show you where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks, i played a bit with the layouts :)
relative layout is just find for now, frame layout isnt working though...

thanks!

Comment: frame layout is working exactly as it was designed, it allows you to stack layouts, so by default they all sit in the top left corner. So do you no longer have a question? if so you should close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eluvatar very much.
I fixed the problem by changing the layout to relative layout (on the "outline" tab -> right click on the "linearlayout" -> change layout -> relativeLayout)

Absolute Layout was what i was looking for though i read that it might be problematic for different screen sizes, so relative layout is the way to go :D

Comment: Absolute is deprecated,don't consider it as an option